# Is it possible for one iphone application to read the logs of another application?

Tags: ios, swift

I need help with acquiring logs for an application without usage of third party or external applications

Comment: Can you add any details if you tried anything and if you did research on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

One application can read other application logs **only if both applications are published by the same account** and put/read logs into a shared folder (developer write correct code and did some other important things, google "sharing data between iOS apps").

But in general, the short answer is "No, it's not possible for an iOS application to read logs of other application". 
At least until the device is jailbroken.

Comment: The apps don't just have to be published by the same account, they should have an App Group defined also. Then you would access the shared container URL from either app/extension

Comment: Absolutely right, I've put it into a "did some other important things" phrase =)